# Javascript window.location.replace doesn't work

Tags: javascript

## TL;DR

A page redirects to other websites with various URLs. Javascript events are used to track if how much time before users are being redirected. Each day around 3000 users, using multiple browsers, go on this page.

Since December 7 the time before redirection is increasing. For some users the redirection doesn't work.

| Date | <4s | 4s | 6s | >6s |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Before Dec. 7 | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% |
| After Dec. 7 | 92% | 7% | 1% | 1% |
| After Jan. 1 | 90% | 6% | 1% | 3% |

### The Question

We have a page that sends an event EVENT A to our analytics and then redirects to an other website after 2s.
For some reason the redirect doesn't work. We added a second event EVENT B sent every 2s then to see when the redirection doesn't work or may take several minutes.

The intended behaviour is:

1. The page loads
2. An event EVENT A is sent to analytics
3. After 2s redirection to an other website
4. Each 2s after send event EVENT B to analytics as long as the user has not been redirected

Here is the page code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tracker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tracker.sendEvent("category", "action}", "label");

    var interval = 2000;
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.replace("https://www.otherwebsite.com");
    }, interval);

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        var i = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
            if (0 !== i) tracker.sendEvent('Error', 'timeout', i * interval);
            i++;
        }, interval);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Since the page is properly rendered and the time is measured client side, I assume the back-end details aren't relevant.**

<s>The page is generated by PHP/Symfony/Apache. The website uses MySQL but for this particular page there's no DB query.</s>

The website is hosted on Digital ocean Ubuntu server.
The server is behind a load balancer.
The load balancer has only one server connected.
The load balancer is behind Cloudflare service.
Cloudflare doesn't cache the page.

The server was generated from a snapshot. The server is recreated every day using terraform.

On December the 6th everything worked properly.
Since December the 7th we started to notice EVENT B on 1/3 of the page. The redirection seems not working.

The code base didn't change.
The server snapshot didn't change.

Any idea why might causes a sudden increase of EVENT B.

Comment: "Each 2s after send event EVENT B to analytics as long as the user has been redirected" Di you mean **not** redirected?

Comment: Are you sure one of the nodes behind the load balancer is not rejecting the connection?

Comment: For how long prior to December 7 was this application being used? In other words: how long was the "golden age" of your app, during which 100% of users were redirected <4s? Days? Months? Years? Also: is this site used primarily by business folks during biz hours, or are your users hitting this site from their homes during the evening (or their mobile devices, potentially around the clock)?

Comment: @Tom The "golden age" lasted at least months. The site is used by individual consumers between 8 am and 11 pm. Half mobile, half desktop.